# Search a list of columns for a set of values in R

Tags: r, list

I have a dataset where I am trying to, by row, check about 25 columns to see if they contain a value from a list. I am not having a problem referencing the list of values to search for, but I am having trouble searching multiple columns at once. I initially thought to create a list of columns to reference, but that doesn't see to be working because you can't use a list.

Right now, I am checking each column individually for a set of values, but I was hoping to do this with less code because I will want to reference this set of columns more than once while cleaning these data. This is what I am currently using:

```
Dx.Elem<-list(c("DX1", "DX2", "DX3", "DX4", "DX5", "DX6", "DX7", "DX8", "DX9", "DX10", "DX11", "DX12", "DX13", "DX14", "DX15", "DX16", "DX17", "DX18", 
              "DX19", "DX20", "DX21", "DX22", "DX23", "DX24", "DX25"))

Dx.Panc9<-list("86384", "86394", "86382", "86392", "86381", "86391", "86383", "86393")

mydata2$Panc9<-0
mydata2$Panc9[mydata2$DX1 %in% Dx.Panc9]<-1
mydata2$Panc9[mydata2$DX2 %in% Dx.Panc9]<-1
mydata2$Panc9[mydata2$DX3 %in% Dx.Panc9]<-1
mydata2$Panc9[mydata2$DX4 %in% Dx.Panc9]<-1
```

The assignment of 1s actually goes to referencing mydata2$DX25, I just cut it off here to spare redundancy.

I have tried substituting referencing a list, but that doesn't work because it can't use a list.

```
mydata2$Panc9[mydata2[, Dx.Elem] %in% Dx.Panc9]<-1
```

and I get this error

```
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Is there a way to use a list to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific case:

```
lapply(mydata2[Dx.Elem], `%in%`, Dx.Panc9)
```

With some example data:

```
# create example data
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
    x1 = round(runif(100, 1, 10)),
    x2 = round(runif(100, 1, 10)),
    x3 = round(runif(100, 1, 10)),
    x4 = round(runif(100, 1, 10)),
    x5 = round(runif(100, 1, 10))
)

# vector of numbers to search for (like Dx.Panc9)
numcheck <- c(2, 4)

# columns of data.frame in which to search (like Dx.Elem)
mycols <- c("x2", "x3", "x4", "x5")

# perform the check
result_list <- lapply(df[mycols], `%in%`, numcheck)
```

This returns a list where each element is a vector of length `nrow(df)`. If your question is whether *any* column contains any the desired numbers, you can do something like this:

```
result_df <- data.frame(result_list)
rowSums(result_df) > 0
```